# Adding prefixes/suffixes to file names without typing it all over again?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, rename

I would like to do something like the following

```
$ tmp=name*
$ mv $tmp new_$tmp
$ ls new_*
$ new_name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type
```

Setting the environment variable seems to work

```
$ $tmp
$ name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type
```

But not when I do the `mv`

```
$ mv $tmp new_$tmp
$ ls new_*
$ new_name*
```

Question: Is there a clever easy way of doing this to save some typing?

Comment: @sim Just so I know, was I breaking a formatting rule, which warranted the edit of my question from bolded to prefixed with "Question:"?

Comment: You pinged @slm incorrectly (I have done it here in case he wants to answer himself). In my opinion, boldface type should be reserved for organizational headings within a question or answer; otherwise, it can be disconcerting.

Comment: Agree with Joseph's comments. Bolding is unnecessary where you used it. Should be reserved for headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always love bash expansion for this:

```
ls
name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type

mv name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type{,_old}

ls
name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type_old
```

This is equivalent to:

```
mv name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type_old
```

For prefixing:

```
ls
name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type

mv {,new_}name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type

ls
new_name-with-stuff-i-dont-want-to-type
```

For easy file renaming:

```
ls
fileFOOname

mv file{FOO,BAR}name

ls
fileBARname
```

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to do something like this while changing some characters, like `name` to `newname`?

Comment: @shootingstars I updated the answer to show how to change text in the middle of the file as well.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, that's typically what you use `zmv` for:

```
autoload zmv # in ~/.zshrc
zmv 'name*' 'tmp_$f'
```

Comment: I've been meaning to try out zsh. another good reason to try it out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one file matching `name*` then `$tmp` contains all these names separated by whitespaces. Treat `$tmp` as an array instead and operate on each element in it:

```
for file in $tmp; do 
    mv "$file" "new_$file"
done
```

Use double quotes to avoid splitting names containing whitepace into several names.

Comment: There's no globbing at the point `tmp=name*`, so `$tmp` contains `name*` (with the verbatim star). It's when calling `mv $tmp` (with unquoted `$tmp`) that the expansion occurs. In your example, the expansion occurs in the `for` statement. Actually it's better to write `for file in name*; do ...` unless you want to use an array as in: `tmp=( name* ); for file in "${tmp[@]}"; do ...`